# 'Other's User Folder...' is grayed out

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I'm using business e-mail and I'm trying to access *File->Open->Other's User Folder...* but the option is grayed out. I need that option in order to join the shared mailbox.

[image: File, Open, Other User's Folder is grayed out on Mac]

Additional information:

- I've placed my cursor in my Inbox (as per this [suggestion](https://semarmendemx.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/outlook-open-other-users-folder-is-greyed-out/)).
- The account is configured using Exchange/Office 365 Account.
- E-mails, calendar and other features works without any issues.

How I can access that option?

Comment: I seem to recall that the owner of the mailbox needs to set the permissions so that you have the appropriate permissions, it is usually done in Outlook itself. But I am unsure if that changed with Office 356

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've noticed, the account needs to be added to a shared mailbox first by the administrator.

Then after hitting *Send & Receive*, the option *Other's User Folder* has been activated successfully.